# Groovy shell returning error on show and purge commands

Tags: groovy

I've been trying to play around with Groovy to see if it would be a good tool to add to the arsenal. I opened up the shell using *groovysh* and was going over the commands. When I got to *show* and *purge* I got back this error(entire contents of shell, formatted):

`Groovy Shell (1.8.5, JVM: 1.6.0_23)

Type 'help' or '\h' for help.`

groovy:000> show
ERROR java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError:
the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for java.lang.Exception do not match. Expected 5 but got 4
        at java_lang_Runnable$run.call (Unknown Source)

groovy:000>

All I've found so far is that this might happen with Java 7 or when trying to integrate, but I'm using Java 6 and a fresh, empty Groovy shell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was reported in [GROOVY-5163](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5163).  The issue is fixed and will be in the 1.8.6 release (which is due to be released soon based on the groovy-dev mailing list discussions).  A workaround in 1.8.5 is to use JDK 7 to run Groovy Shell.

Also, just want to point out that ***groovyConsole*** is another nice tool (Swing based graphical editor) for playing around with Groovy.